# Master Page Menus Are Left Aligned but dependent pages menus showing in Center

Tags: asp.net

I have created MasterPage Menus which is Left aligned and seems good but the dependent pages Menus are showing in Center of the Table Column.

I am using Design View to align the controls.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Any suggestions about how to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you share the code of master page. Also, are you using CSS or inline styling?

Comment: Hm.. After you comment I just went through the Source of each dependent pages and I found Center keyword in those Html source and I just replaced the center to Left and now it's looking good.  Thanks for your comment which made me to fix my issue :)

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the source and replaced Center to Left :)